# detect if inside a LaTeX footnote and get its bounds?

Tags: latex, auctex

**Q:** how do I get the bounds of a LaTeX footnote?

I'd like to be able to detect, programmatically, if point is inside a LaTeX footnote environment.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to extract the beginning and end points of the footnote.  How would one do so?

I'm aware of the `TeX-current-macro` function, but it's not quite what I need.  If, for example, point is inside a citation inside a footnote, it will stop at detecting the citation.  It also does not provide the bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find anything ready-made, but it turns out not to be too hard to write up with a combination of `TeX-current-macro`, `TeX-find-macro-start`, and `TeX-find-macro-boundaries`.  This function will also serve as a predicate, and could be adapted to other kinds of macros pretty easily:

```
(defun LaTeX-footnote-bounds ()
  "Return bounds of a LaTeX footnote as a cons cell, or nil if
not in a footnote."
  (let ((macro (TeX-current-macro)))
    (when macro
      (save-excursion
        (while (not (equal "footnote" macro))
          (goto-char (- (TeX-find-macro-start)
                        (if (equal "footnote" (setq macro (TeX-current-macro)))
                            0
                          1))))
        (TeX-find-macro-boundaries)))))
```