# Why isn't (TeX-current-macro) a member of '(chapter section)?

Tags: elisp, auctex

Consider the variable `TeX-current-macro` raised in the recent question [detect if inside a LaTeX footnote and get its bounds?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7929/2609) also in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7634/2690. 
I would like to determine if I am inside the macros `chapter` or `section` in a latex file, I can write define a function which shows `yes` if it is the case, otherwise `no`.
Of course I can use the following which does the job.

```
 (defun foo-test () (interactive)
    (if (or (equal (TeX-current-macro) "chapter") 
(equal (TeX-current-macro) "section")) 
(message "yes") (message "no"))
    )
```

But it is long. Like in my previous question [What is the easiest way to check if a character belongs to a particular set of characters?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7879/2609), I am wondering if there is a better way to do it.
Inspired by the answer https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7880/2609, I tried the below code, but unfortunately it doesn't work. 
I also tried with `memq` instead of `member` but it doesn't work either.

```
 (defun foo-test () (interactive)
    (if (member (TeX-current-macro) '(chapter section)) 
(message "yes") (message "no"))
    )
```

Any solution about checking if the value of a  variable belong to a list of elements is welcomed.

Comment: The second example doesn't work because you are not comparing objects of the same type, you are comparing symbols to strings. `"chapter"` does not equal `'chapter`

Comment: Put `chapter` and `section` as strings rather than symbols, since `TeX-current-macro` returns a string.

Comment: @JordonBiondo let me ask what is the correct syntax for doing it.

Comment: @Dan let me ask what is the correct way to do it.

Comment: `(member "a" '("a" "b"))` will be true, `(member "a" '(a b))` will not because "a" is a string and 'a is a symbol, so just change `'(chapter section)` from your second example to `'("chapter" "section")` so it's a list of strings instead of a list of symbols. `'chapter` and `"chapter"` look alike, but they are really no more equal than `3` and `"three"`

Comment: @JordonBiondo thank you very much for your clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`member`'s comparison is done with `equal`, so you can't mix types.  Your example uses *symbols* for `chapter` and `section`, but `TeX-current-macro` returns a string.  Hence, you want your list to have strings as well:

```
(defun foo-test () (interactive)
  (if (member (TeX-current-macro) '("chapter" "section")) 
      (message "yes")
    (message "no")))
```

Examples:

```
(setq macro-names '("chapter" "section"))
(member "chapter" macro-names)          ; => ("chapter" "section")
(member "puppies" macro-names)          ; => nil
```